# How to create sliding window of 2 seconds width from irregular timeseries data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a set of timeseries data across a few different days. The data looks as follows. I would like to separate all the data into 2 seconds intervals and create a sliding window and then label each window with a label of "stay" or "leave". I tried using the pandas built-in windows but the window only lets me choose to have window size of integers (records in the dataframe), not time of 2 seconds etc.

Is making a sliding window necessary for this task? I looked online on how to do machine learning on time series data and it was mentioned that using windows is one of the basics of working with time series data.

Currently, I am thinking to generate all the 2 second intervals, and replicate each record (each record lasts from timestamp to timestamp of next record) according to the relevant timestamp in the original DataFrame to create a new DataFrame with records of 2 second intervals of the time series.

```
    leave   timeframe   confidence  restaurant  timestamp   event
0   false   2021-12-17T12:06:19+0800 to 2021-12-17T12:30:2...   2   Bistro NTT  2021-12-17 12:05:19+08:00   walking
1   false   2021-12-17T12:06:19+0800 to 2021-12-17T12:30:2...   2   Bistro NTT  2021-12-17 12:06:07+08:00   Previous activity ended. Recalculating activit...
2   false   2021-12-17T12:06:19+0800 to 2021-12-17T12:30:2...   2   Bistro NTT  2021-12-17 12:07:04+08:00   stationary
3   false   2021-12-17T12:06:19+0800 to 2021-12-17T12:30:2...   2   Bistro NTT  2021-12-17 12:08:35+08:00   Previous activity ended. Recalculating activit...
4   false   2021-12-17T12:06:19+0800 to 2021-12-17T12:30:2...   2   Bistro NTT  2021-12-17 12:08:47+08:00   stationary
```

as of now, I managed to create a dummy dataframe, all I need to do now is to fit my old dataframe onto the new dataframe. Basically, fit the graph into this new 2 second interval dataframe

```
rs = pd.date_range(start=timeseries.index[0], end=timeseries.index[-1], freq='2s') #index=timeseries.resample('2s').interpolate().iloc[1:].index
dummy_frame = pd.DataFrame(np.NaN, index=rs, columns=timeseries.columns)
dummy_frame.head()
```

output:

```
    leave   timeframe   confidence  restaurant  event
2021-12-17 12:05:19+08:00   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2021-12-17 12:05:21+08:00   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2021-12-17 12:05:23+08:00   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2021-12-17 12:05:25+08:00   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2021-12-17 12:05:27+08:00   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

[image: sample data plotted]

Comment: Can you update your post with the output of `df.head()`?

Comment: ok done. the main columns i m working with are timestamp, event, and leave. the timeframe is mostly there for me to determine which are leave events in this sample data

Comment: you need to groupby event then rolling on timestamp (2s) and check if there is any true in leave column?

Comment: Cannot determine the resolution of the second from your data. If the data is sample at regular interval, you may consider to sample it using `.iloc()` of position.  It should be faster.

Comment: i m hoping to apply machine learning actually. I label windows as stay or leave depending on the value of leave column. I m not sure about the groupby event because I think that being stationary after leaving can also occur.

Comment: @yoonghm the data is not sampled at regular intervals actually. I m using coremotion from iOS and each event lasts from the timestamp until the next event

Comment: So why event is important?

Comment: i m observing the events of users while in a restaurant. i m hoping to train a model to be able to identify users leaving a restaurant after checking in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I have done so far:

```
def normalize_ts(df, limit=3):
    unique_val = df.timeframe.unique()
    index = 0
    df_list = list()
    for val in unique_val:
        if index > limit:
            break
        df_filtered = df[df['timeframe']==val]
        df_list.append(normalize(df_filtered))
        index += 1
        
    return df_list
        
def normalize(df):
    #generate dummy dataframes to store values of 2s intervals
    rs = pd.date_range(start=df.index[0], end=df.index[-1], freq='2s') 
    #index=timeseries.resample('2s').interpolate().iloc[1:].index
    dummy_frame = pd.DataFrame(np.NaN, index=rs, columns=df.columns)
    
    idx = 0
    
    #fill in values to dummy dataframe
    for val in range(len(df.index)):
        if df.index[val] == df.index[-1]:
            if idx == len(dummy_frame.index):
                break
            dummy_index = dummy_frame.index[idx]
            df_index = df.index[val]

            dummy_frame.loc[dummy_index, 'leave'] = df.loc[df_index, 'leave']
            dummy_frame.loc[dummy_index, 'timeframe'] = df.loc[df_index, 'timeframe']
            dummy_frame.loc[dummy_index, 'confidence'] = df.loc[df_index, 'confidence']
            dummy_frame.loc[dummy_index, 'restaurant'] = df.loc[df_index, 'restaurant']
            dummy_frame.loc[dummy_index, 'event'] = df.loc[df_index, 'event']
            break
        while(True):
            if idx == len(dummy_frame.index):
                break
            dummy_index = dummy_frame.index[idx]
            df_index = df.index[val]
            df_index2 = df.index[val+1]

            if dummy_index >= df_index and df_index2 > dummy_index:
                dummy_frame.loc[dummy_index, 'leave'] = df.loc[df_index, 'leave']
                dummy_frame.loc[dummy_index, 'timeframe'] = df.loc[df_index, 'timeframe']
                dummy_frame.loc[dummy_index, 'confidence'] = df.loc[df_index, 'confidence']
                dummy_frame.loc[dummy_index, 'restaurant'] = df.loc[df_index, 'restaurant']
                dummy_frame.loc[dummy_index, 'event'] = df.loc[df_index, 'event']
            else:
                break
            idx += 1
            
    return dummy_frame

timeseries = timeseries.set_index('timestamp')
dataframes = normalize_ts(timeseries, 10)
merged = pd.concat(dataframes).reset_index()
merged.rename(columns={'index': 'timestamp'}, inplace=True)
```

This gives me an output like the following:

```
    timestamp   leave   timeframe   confidence  restaurant  event
0   2021-12-17 12:05:19+08:00   false   2021-12-17T12:06:19+0800 to 2021-12-17T12:30:2...   2.0 Bistro NTT  walking
1   2021-12-17 12:05:21+08:00   false   2021-12-17T12:06:19+0800 to 2021-12-17T12:30:2...   2.0 Bistro NTT  walking
2   2021-12-17 12:05:23+08:00   false   2021-12-17T12:06:19+0800 to 2021-12-17T12:30:2...   2.0 Bistro NTT  walking
3   2021-12-17 12:05:25+08:00   false   2021-12-17T12:06:19+0800 to 2021-12-17T12:30:2...   2.0 Bistro NTT  walking
4   2021-12-17 12:05:27+08:00   false   2021-12-17T12:06:19+0800 to 2021-12-17T12:30:2...   2.0 Bistro NTT  walking
```

This may not be the most efficient, but now that I am able to get the values of the irregular timeseries data into a regular interval, I think I should be able to start working on the windowing function for time series machine learning thing

Answer (score 1):

What you expect is not clear, can you test:

```
out = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='2s', key='timestamp'))['leave'] \
        .apply(lambda x: 'leave' if any(x == 'true') else 'stay')
print(out.head(10))

# Output:
timestamp
2021-12-22 11:35:00    leave
2021-12-22 11:35:02    leave
2021-12-22 11:35:04    leave
2021-12-22 11:35:06     stay
2021-12-22 11:35:08    leave
2021-12-22 11:35:10    leave
2021-12-22 11:35:12    leave
2021-12-22 11:35:14     stay
2021-12-22 11:35:16     stay
2021-12-22 11:35:18     stay
Freq: 2S, Name: leave, dtype: object
```

Setup:

```
np.random.seed(2021)
dti = pd.date_range('2021-12-22 11:35', freq='1s', periods=60)
df = pd.DataFrame({'leave': np.random.choice(['false', 'true'], len(dti)),
                   'timestamp': dti, 'event': [2]*len(dti)})
print(df.head(10))

# Output:
   leave           timestamp  event
0  false 2021-12-22 11:35:00      2
1   true 2021-12-22 11:35:01      2
2   true 2021-12-22 11:35:02      2
3  false 2021-12-22 11:35:03      2
4   true 2021-12-22 11:35:04      2
5  false 2021-12-22 11:35:05      2
6  false 2021-12-22 11:35:06      2
7  false 2021-12-22 11:35:07      2
8   true 2021-12-22 11:35:08      2
9  false 2021-12-22 11:35:09      2
```

Comment: it generated these ```2021-12-17 12:05:18+08:00    stay
2021-12-17 12:05:20+08:00    stay
2021-12-17 12:05:22+08:00    stay
2021-12-17 12:05:24+08:00    stay
2021-12-17 12:05:26+08:00    stay
2021-12-17 12:05:28+08:00    stay``` however, all the data is labeled stay. probably because the leave column are strings not booleans

Comment: My bad!!! I fixed my answer.

Comment: ```2021-12-17 12:30:23+08:00 true``` gives a leave output, ```2021-12-17 12:30:47+08:00 true``` also gives leave output, however, the 2 second groups in between these are all stay

Comment: Can you check on my setup example please?

Comment: could this groupby replicate the records of my original dataframe? ie for my first record turn it into multiple 2 second windows (record/rows) with the same values for each column until the next record?

Comment: the groupby is looking like what I m hoping to achieve, but its not quite there.

Comment: Yes it's possible using `aggregate`. I have to go. I will update my answer later.

Comment: very much appreciated. this is my first time working with time series data in machine learning, so it is quite hard to illustrate what i want to do